What does it mean by Power BI report references a row with RLS?

Keep in mind that if a Power BI report references a row with RLS
configured then the same message displays as for a deleted or
non-existing field. To these users, it looks like the report is
broken.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/security/service-admin-row-level-security#considerations-and-limitations
I'm looking for an example to understand what this means.

It's stated that if the report is throwing error by saying deleted column or field does not exist in the model (in your configured RLS column or table). That's something wrong with the model, nothing to do with RLS or its configuration.

What does references a row with RLS mean?

Only thing that comes to mind is OLS, not RLS. With object-level security you can filter out entire columns and, if a visual uses said column, it will display an error for the users/groups that have that rule configured. Can't reproduce any example for row-level security. If you filter out an entire table (by using FALSE() e.g.), the visual using fields from that table will be empty, but there won't be an error.

On the other hand, if you configure a rule in RLS for a specific column, and later you delete that column for whatever reason, the entire report will show an error because RLS couldn't be executed.

Lets say you have a Dim table with users with a column called user_name and you are using USERPRINCIPALNAME()  to filter out the users. In the later part if you deleted the user table which means RLS has been broken. Hence, this error.

@AmilaMGunawardana If you use RLS on a table and then delete that table, the RLS gets deleted as well, so no error would appear. In your example, an error would appear if the users table still exists but the user_name column doesn't.

@PhobosFerro yes That's the exact example I want to give. Deleted or renamed a column will cause this issue. Thank you!!!

Ok so this has nothing to do with OLS? Can someone post an answer so I can close this.

Row Level Security (RLS) gets checked on report load. If a rule on a table can't be checked because the filtered field no longer exists, all visuals referencing that table will break.
So for example, imagine you have users John and Tim, and a table Users that contains the field email. 
Then you add a filter role on table Users for user Tim that filters out the email field.

If you delete the Users table, nothing will happen, since the RLS filter will get deleted with it. Both users will be able to see the same unfiltered data.
If you delete the email field, Tim won't be able to see any visual that references the Users table. Displaying the same error it would if a field on that visual no longer existed, but with a different error message once you click on See details:



While editing the Dataset, an error will appear informing the user that one or more RLS filters have errors:

